# Adding a script within HTML5 which is within php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am facing a problem adding my Google Adsense code in the code below.

```
<?php
function ww_header(){
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>

// I Want to paste my Google Adsense code here

</head>
?>
```

This is how my Google Adsense code looks like

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">            
</script>
<script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
      google_ad_client: "ca-pub-77XXXXXXXXXXX",
      enable_page_level_ads: true
 });
</script>
```

I tried using echo and include.
The Adsense script conflicts with HTML5 and php since the head tag is within the php.
Is there any way i can write the Adsense code without altering the positions of php and HTML.

Comment: Why do you need to echo all of that? There are syntax errors in your PHP as well.

Comment: Don't use `echo` use `?>` to close the php section and then paste the google snippet

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `echo "` (with double quotes).  Your script code also has double quotes.  So you need to either escape the double quotes in your script tag, or use single quotes for your `echo` instead.  Does this work for you?

```
function ww_header(){
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page title</title>

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">            
    </script>
    <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-77XXXXXXXXXXX",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Your content here...
    </body>
    </html>';
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Go ahead and mark it as the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function ww_header()
{
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'>            
        </script>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
      google_ad_client: 'ca-pub-77XXXXXXXXXXX',
      enable_page_level_ads: true
 });
</script>
</head>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but just to solve exactly what you're asking, try this:

```
<?php
function ww_header() {
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
           <title>Page title</title>

           <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">            
           </script>
           <script>
           (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-77XXXXXXXXXXX",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
           </script>

           </head>';
?>
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck :)